Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postman-library-api.glitch.me
I was trying to make the exercises from the tutorial provided by Postman, API 101: API Fundamentals after watching the video provided and studying the slides. The problem I am currently experiencing revolves around the endpoints provided by Postman: every time I try even to make a basic GET request using this baseUrl: https://postman-library-api.glitch.me and the subsequent specific endpoint: https://postman-library-api.glitch.me/books, I always receive an error both on the console and in the Response tab:

Could not send request - Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postman-library-api.glitch.me

and:
GET https://postman-library-api.glitch.me/
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND postman-library-api.glitch.me
Request Headers
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.39.0
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 70e0a3d1-63d1-4072-a8c9-8581eae2f115
Host: postman-library-api.glitch.me
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive

I have tried to check on my browser the endpoint, and I receive again a message warning me about the invalidity of this endpoint, but people I know that has followed my same steps were able to work on the same endpoint. If someone could help me in solving this issue, I would be very grateful.


This seems to be a problem with your internet connecdtion or your DNS provider. It seems your system is not able to resolve that host to a valid IP address. What happens if you open a terminal and type nslookup postman-library-api.glitch.me ?

I used to have the same issue with GET https://simple-tool-rental-api.glitch.me
Simple laptop restart resolved the issue for me.
